# Book about distances for data science (can't remember the name)

Tags: metric, reference-request, books

I saw a book somewhere that listed a big amount of mathematical distance functions (the usual euclidean norms, the discrete distance, the hamming distance, etc) used for data science.

The name of the book might be similar to "101 metrics for data science". I cannot find it. Does anyone know about it (or a similar book)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a book, but a webpage with Open Source code is the [ELKI Data Mining](https://elki-project.github.io/algorithms/distances) library of distance functions.